# How to create a temporary table in WordPress when inserting values

Tags: wordpress

How to create a temporary table in WordPress then insert values into it? I tried this code, but how to insert values to it

```
global $wpdb;

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $generate(
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sid int(11),
    cid int(11),
    tid int(11),
    lid int(11),
    lgid int(11),\
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
) $charset_collate;";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );

$Results=$wpdb->get_results("INSERT INTO $generate values('NULL',12,2,3,1,1)");
$Results=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $generate ");
```

Comment: Your last column in the `CREATE TABLE` has a trailing comma. Change `lgid Int,` to `lgid Int`. There may be other problems, but you would have to be more specific than "doesn't work" - that is not an accurate fault report.

Comment: At a guess, your `INSERT` statement contains SQL injection vulnerabilities too.